# Problem with google calendar API (deleted items)

Tags: events, google-calendar-api, spam, recycle-bin

I have an issue with the Google Calendar API that is not working properly.
Normally we import the calendar items from ...@ps-calendar.iam.gserviceaccount.com ... 
when they create this calendar entry we get this item in the google trash.
When I would like to restore this item - I can't.
Maybe it is a SPAM Problem?